# Click jquery menu item using selenium webdriver

Tags: jquery, python, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I am new to selenium and I am using python but I have a small question on navigating to Jquery menu in Internet Explorer. I would like to navigate to a menu which looks something like this *Tools > Data Load > **Data Load***. I am pasting my HTML code below. I don't know which one to use for clicking on the last menu item Data load which was marked in Bold.

Please some one help me. I googled it every where but could not get right answer.

```
<LI class="mainmenu topmenu" sub_menu="1" level="1" jQuery1340790605409="12">Tools 
<UL style="DISPLAY: none; TOP: 49px; LEFT: 383px" class="mainmenu submenu" jQuery1340790605409="214">
<LI class="mainmenu submenupointer submenu " sub_menu="1" level="2" global_level="1" menu_id="891" jQuery1340790605409="54">Data Load 
<UL style="DISPLAY: none; TOP: 1px; LEFT: 109px" class="mainmenu subsubmenu" jQuery1340790605409="232">
<LI class="mainmenu subsubmenu" sub_menu="0" level="3" url_path="/Apps/Tools/DataLoad/DataLoad/FileList.asp" jQuery1340790605409="172">Data Load 
<LI class="mainmenu subsubmenu" sub_menu="0" level="3" url_path="/Apps/Tools/DataLoad/DataExtracts/template.asp" jQuery1340790605409="174">Data Extracts 
<LI class="mainmenu subsubmenu" sub_menu="0" level="3" url_path="/Apps/Tools/DataLoad/BehaviorMatrix/BehaviorMatrix.asp" jQuery1340790605409="176">Behavior Matrix </LI></UL>
```

Comment: Right now I am unable to judge whether to use id or class. Because there is no id and it has a class name with similar name "mainmenu subsubmenu". Can some one help me on this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot see the **DataLoad** submenu without clicking or hovering over the following steps - 
Tools -> Data Load -> Data Load .

Then you will have to use the selenium Actions class to make the mouse hover(navigate) over tools -> DataLoad elements etc. You can check this link for more information on [Actions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#action-chains) .

And regarding whether to use id or class? I will suggest you use linkText or partialLinkText to find the element you are looking to click on. eg - search for elements where linkText is equal to `"DataLoad"` .